# Apple Aluminum Keyboard Function Keys Broken in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

Using the latest Apple Aluminum keyboard, the "fn" key seems to have stopped working. I'm not talking about being swapped with standard OSX, I mean the "fn" key doesn't register whatsoever, rendering, for example, F12 exactly the same as holding "fn" + F12.

The strange thing is that I swapped an older version of the exact same keyboard that was working fine... it appears that the hardware has changed here...

I've downloaded modprobe hid_apple to no success... I'm willing to jump through some hoops here... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This question belongs on AskUbuntu - I've flagged it so that it is migrated :)

Comment: Same here, I think after updating from 3.19.0-58-generic
to 3.19.0-59-generic